# Ajax on Success message

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I don't have much experience with ajax I want to use .post and in and if condition let the user know it succeed or not.

This is my .post code:

```
$.post("ajaxRegistering.php",{
                  name: name,
                  lastname: lastname,
                  secondlastname: secondlastname,
                  usernameone: usernameone,
                  email: email,
                  passwordone: passwordone,
                  studentnumberone: studentnumberone,
                  temp: temp
            },
                function(data,status){
                  // alert("Data: " + name + "\nStatus: " + status) ;
                  sweetAlert("Successfully", " created your account.", "success") ;

            }) ;
```

Normal ajax that actually runs well but I'm still unable to add on failure case:

```
$.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "website.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(dataone){
              sweetAlert("Successfully", " rolled in momentoSagrado.", "success") ;
            } 

          }) ;
```

Can someone help me out I think is something simple that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: How can I call a message if it fails or if not success it still appear the message at least on .post :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `error` to a function in your [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "website.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(dataone) {
        sweetAlert("Successfully"," rolled in momentoSagrado.","success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        // error occured
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok I get it now :). I still don't understand this... I have some php code that checks if username already exist unfortunately error will never execute because technically there is not any during the execution.

Comment: How can I trigger the error or something like that from the Php? If is possible

Comment: You don't need to trigger an error. Just have the PHP return something like "username taken", and use an `if` statement that runs the alternate code if the returned data contains that string.

Comment: So with ajax I just call it in a tab or can get a return value from php to ajax?

Comment: Yes, in the case of AJAX, using `echo` statements in the PHP code will write to the variable which is returned back.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

per [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
`.post()` is short hand for:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

so implement a success function like this:

```
$.post( "website.php", function( data ) {
    sweetAlert("Successfully", " created your account.", "success") ;
});
```

As far as getting the error on `.post()`..  you'll need to chain the **fail** function  (from docs) ...

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```